# Sizing an emergency generator for an old AC with a missing label

Tags: electrical, hvac, generator

My daughter is trying to work out the current draw of an old AC with a worn label. She's trying to size an emergency generator that will power critical appliances in the event of a power outage. The AC label is completely worn, so there is no model number or energy specifications.

Some details about the AC: The home inspector and a handyman have independently told her they think it is from the 1990s, but can't be sure. It cools the 2000 sq ft house without problem throughout the hot Phoenix summer. It is on a 220V dedicated circuit with a 50A breaker and a 60A switch. The circuit breaker has never tripped. She has the hourly energy usage for the whole house, and she never goes above 11kW (a 118 degree day, with the AC, other household appliances, a 1hp pool pump and a 3.5 kW EV charger going). Typical mid summer hourly energy use peaks at 7-8kW.

I'm looking for answers for whether it's effective to estimate usage requirements for a generator using the circuit breaker, the hourly usage data, perhaps, taking apart the condenser unit to get to the compressor and putting a clamp ammeter on it, or maybe something else.  Please don't suggest she replaces a perfectly running air conditioner, especially not with the suggestion that it is inefficient, as it is impossible to make an informed decision about energy savings without actually answering this question about the amp draw first.

Comment: It was kind of implicit in your question that the emergency generator has to run the AC, but have you considered excluding the AC?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate OP is in Phoenix. It's ac or head to a hotel.

Comment: The problem is, the energy usage data is *hourly averages*. Presumably the A/C cycles on and off during that time.

Comment: @Ruskes yes, though as I understand it AC circuits are often oversized to allow for the starting current. So 40 Amps would be an upper limit.

Comment: @Ruskes and re no 220 V in Arizona. Sure there is. It just depends on where you measure it. You get 120V service. You can wire that to provide 240, but it isn't going to BE 240 at the load. 230 at best, but often closer to 220 if you're a ways away from your panel.

Comment: @DeNovo -- have you considered that modern inverter ACs are capable of "soft starting" instead of bogging down the generator with a monster inrush load on startup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> She's trying to size an emergency generator.

Then the size you are looking for is going to be significantly *more* than the A/C, probably closer to the typical summer day peak.

> The home inspector and a handyman have independently told her they think it is from the 1990s, but can't be sure.

Then it is likely due for replacement. That is bad news in terms of an extra big cost. It is good news because new units are *much* more energy efficient. Meaning both lower energy costs and a lower peak load, which means a smaller generator. So it may be worth considering sooner rather than later.

> It is on a 220V dedicated circuit with a 50A breaker and a 60A switch.

Which is really a 240V dedicated circuit. 50A should indicate a *maximum* of 40A continuous, so that's the upper limit for this part of the generator load. 60A switch is irrelevant - that is a standard "big enough for any A/C system" disconnect switch.

> The circuit breaker has never tripped.

Good, because if it did then that would be a sign of a serious problem. In fact, A/C (and other continuous loads) have oversized (125% over the actual continuous load) breakers which means trips should be extremely rare unless there is a component failure.

> She has the hourly energy usage for the whole house, and she never goes above 11kW (a 118 degree day, with the AC, other household appliances, a 1hp pool pump and a 3.5 kW EV charger going). Typical mid summer hourly energy use peaks at 7-8kW.

These are useful numbers. If 11 kW is the peak of the peak and that includes 3.5 kW EV charging, subtract the 3.5 kW and you get 7.5 kW, which is right in line with the "typical" peak of 7 - 8 kW. Obviously you wouldn't be charging the EV from the generator, so that puts a new maximum needed of 8 kW. Which is around 33 A, quite a bit below the theoretical max. of the A/C at 40A, and includes other loads as well.

> putting a clamp ammeter on it

That actually would give you a real-world number. But I wouldn't take it all apart, just put a clamp on one of the hots feeding the A/C inside the breaker panel.

So it looks like your target is on the order of 8 kW. Probably a good idea to upsize a bit because a generator will typically run better if it isn't being pushed to the limit.

But seriously take a look at a new air conditioner. Could save a *lot* in electricity.

Comment: To add to the excellent answer.  Being that old, it may be using a refrigerant that is now considered toxic or causes more harm to the environment.  It may not be possible to re-gas it.  So, another reason to upgrade it.

Comment: @RohitGupta True. On the other hand, as long as it stays sealed and operational that is not a problem at all - the damage was done in production (long time ago) and in disposal (which has pretty strict rules in the US). But it does mean that if a repair is needed that involves the refrigerant then that is almost certainly time to replace the whole thing.

Comment: She's not interested in replacing a perfectly working AC.  Sensible answer otherwise. Thank you. The generator won't run the whole house. I'm curious whether there are any references re whether an AC's average hourly usage is a good estimate to use for sizing the generator, to account for the fact that the compressor isn't running 60 minutes every hour.  We can back out an estimate of the AC contribution, but...

Comment: ...say you size for the average hourly load, but (made up numbers) for 30 of those 60 minutes the AC is pulling twice as much as its average would suggest, along the fridge is pulling 3 times what its average would suggest, and sometimes they coincide. Add the startup surge of each load, and there could be a big difference between the minute to minute and the average hourly load.

Comment: @DeNovo you don't size for an average load over any time period. You must size a generator for the maximum or peak load.

Comment: One catch with the "8 kW" figure is that if that is hourly (as my utility currently gives me info. as a regular consumer) rather than 15 min. (the industry standard for smart meter reporting) then it might not give a true picture, depending on your a/c duty cycle. So a clamp meter when running as a sanity check on the A/C current requirement is not a bad idea.